# Contact Trigger - MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call

Tags: apex, trigger

I figured I'd learn Apex by trying to convert processes that I build to triggers in a sandbox.

I'm trying to pass some contact information onto the header of the Account when the Contact has been identified as the primary contact.

here's what I have so far:

```
trigger ContactStuff on Contact (before insert, after insert, after update) {    
List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
for (Contact c : Trigger.new) {
    if(c.Primary_Account_Contact__c == true){
        Account a = new Account(
            Id               = c.Account.Id,
            Contact_Email__c = c.Email,
            Fax__c           = c.Fax,
            Full_Name__c     = c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName,
            Telephone__c     = c.Phone);
        accList.add(a);            
    }

}
update accList; 
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Error:Apex trigger ContactOnCreate caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: ContactOnCreate: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: []: Trigger.ContactOnCreate: line 32, column 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Account.Id` value is going to be null in the trigger context. You can't pull in parent fields. But in this case, you don't have to. Just use `AccountId` instead.

You should also:

- make sure you [only fire this trigger on your after events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm)

  > There are two types of triggers:
  >
  > - *Before triggers* are used to update or validate record values before they’re saved to the database.
  > - *After triggers* are used to access field values that are set by the system (such as a record's Id or LastModifiedDate field), and to affect changes in other records, such as logging into an audit table or firing asynchronous events with a queue. The records that fire the after trigger are read-only.
- consider implementing a [Handler Pattern](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices)
- consider implementing a [Service Layer](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_patterns_sl)
- add error handling

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the `Id` field of the contact's parent Account. Without a query it is not possible to do so. However, the `AccountId` field is like a formula to the Account's field, and it is available for use without a query in your situation.

The error is thrown because since you are trying to access that field without the query, it is returning a `null` value to the created Account. And `update` operations need an Id.